# Update KTable based on partial data attributes

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to update a KTable with partial data of an object.
Eg. User object is 
`{"id":1, "name":"Joe", "age":28}`
The object is being streamed into a topic and grouped by key into KTable.
Now the user object is updated partially as follows `{"id":1, "age":33}` and streamed into table. But the updated table looks as follows `{"id":1, "name":null, "age":28}`. 
The expected output is `{"id":1, "name":"Joe", "age":33}`.
How can I use Kafka streams and spring cloud streams to achieve the expected output. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code

```
 @Bean
        public Function<KStream<String, User>, KStream<String, User>> process() {
            return input -> input.map((key, user) -> new KeyValue<String, User>(user.getId(), user))
                    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), new JsonSerde<>(User.class))).reduce((user1, user2) -> {
                        user1.merge(user2);
                        return user1;
                    }, Materialized.as("allusers")).toStream();
        }
```

and modified the User object with below code:

```
    public void merge(Object newObject) {
        assert this.getClass().getName().equals(newObject.getClass().getName());
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            for (Field newField : newObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (field.getName().equals(newField.getName())) {
                    try {
                        field.set(this, newField.get(newObject) == null ? field.get(this) : newField.get(newObject));
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this the right approach or any other approach in KStreams?

Comment: Your approach is correct. As @xcrazy360 mentioned, you should create a new object that you return but not mutate the passed in current aggregate and new value.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested your merge code, and it seems to be working as expected. But since your result after the `reduce` is `{"id":1, "name":null, "age":28}`, I can think of two things:

- Your state isn't being updated at all, since no attribute has changed.
- Maybe you have a serialization problem, since the string attribute is null, but the other int attributes are fine.

My guess is that, because you are mutating the original object and return the same value, kafka streams doesn't detect that as a change and won't store the new state. Actually, you shouldn't mutate your object, since it could lead to non-determinism depending on your pipeline.

Try to change your `merge` function to create a new `User` object, and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Thank you @xcrazy360 for the response. Without the '''merge''' the data after update was '''{"id":1, "name":null, "age":28}''' . With '''merge''', the table is being updated. I wanted to know if this is the right approach in KStreams and Cloud Streams world or is there any other more efficient approach. I am new to Streaming development, hence this question.

Comment: Your approach is correct. As @xcrazy360 mentioned, you should create a new object that you return but not mutate the passed in current aggregate and new value.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the recommended generic approach for merging the 2 objects, please feel to comment here. For this to work the the object being merged should have an empty constructor.

```
     public <T> T mergeObjects(T first, T second) {
        Class<?> clazz = first.getClass();
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        Object newObject = null;
        try {
            newObject = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value1 = field.get(first);
                Object value2 = field.get(second);
                Object value = (value2 == null) ? value1 : value2;
                field.set(newObject, value);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (T) newObject;
    }
```